# Why can't i set more cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using this code to set multiple cookies, but I can set only two. Why can't this set more cookies ?

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays,path)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ("; path=/");
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays,path)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ("; path=/");
}


function getCookie(c_name)
{
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
       x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==c_name)
          {
              return unescape(y);
          }
    }
 }

var cookieToSet = "1";
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    if(getCookie(i)) {
        cookieToSet = i+1;
        break;
    }
}
setCookie(cookieToSet, 1, 365);
```

What i want to achieve is show different messages for a returning visitors to my site. not just for the 1st time visit but until their 4th visit .

Comment: this is your code for getCookies... can I see set cookies code?

Comment: also, how many characters is the resulting cookie?

Comment: @todd sorry, i didn't know i missed it.  I added it above. by characters you mean ?

Comment: i mean what is the character count of `document.cookie`?

Comment: did this work for you? Have you checked the demo? if so, you should mark as correct.

Comment: @todd i just checked it out, the three cookies are set at the same time

Answer (score 0):

try simplifying your code to set cookies this way:

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/eade6dab8aa88aaa16e71dd5f81bafeb?editors=101)

```
function setCookie(key, val){
     document.cookie = key+'='+val;
}

setCookie('foo', 123);
setCookie('bar', 123);
setCookie('baz', 123);

document.body.innerHTML = document.cookie; // for demo purposes
```

## edit II

you could always check if the cookie exists before assigning it

```
function setCookie(key, val){
     if (cookieExists(key)) return;
     document.cookie = key+'='+val;
}

function cookieExists(key) {
  return !!~document.cookie.split(';').map(function(a) { 
    return a.split('=')[0].trim(); 
  }).indexOf(key);
}

function setCookies(cookies) {
  var keys = Object.keys(cookies);
  for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++){
    var key = keys[i],
        val = cookies[key];

    if (cookieExists(key)) break;
    setCookie(key, val);
  }
}

var cookies = {
  'foo': Date.now(),
  'bar': 123,
  'baz': 123
}

setCookies(cookies);

document.body.innerHTML = document.cookie;
```

Comment: wow, didn't figure out it was this simple to set cookies with js. but @todd the three cookies are set at the same time, on the first visit.

Comment: I am not sure if i am getting how this works. What i was expecting to happen was ... i set "foo" the first time, then if "foo" exists  i set the second cookies "bar", and if the second cookie exists i want to set the third "Baz" and so on ...

Comment: :-( still sets the three at the same time .